# Use File Containing Variables across different projects

Tags: java, android, game-development

I am trying to make a new file var.java in project A such that it includes some variables . Now I need to use the same variable while passing to an intent from project B . 
Till now what I am doing is that we are defining the variables once in project A and then in B and I need to reduce the code redundancy.
I had an idea to configure the whole project B in A settings.gradle file but since I am just needing the particular file var.java in A there is no point of doing that.
Can anyone please suggest some way to fix this.

Comment: Create an object that has these variables, and pass the object around.

Comment: This can only be used if we are talking about one project only . But since we are using two projects I am not sure how this will help.

Comment: Will there be code reuse? That's a good reason for libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're trying to achieve is reusable code to be used among several projects. So the logical approach would be to create a shared library to use in all projects that need it. Extract all general purpose code needed for multiple projects into its own project and add it as a dependency with maven or Gradle or add the library in the old fashioned way manually to your projects.

Of course I am assuming you are talking about information that is already existent at compile time, constant values that do not change during runtime. But as you've written it, it doesn't sound as if you were sharing information during runtime, so a small, simple library would do the trick.